# Ajuda com Trigger Mutating

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g

Estou criando uma trigger que precisa ser disparada através de uma tabela, mesmo criando uma COMPOUND TRIGGER ela acusa erro de mutating, tenho conhecimento de que não posso realizar um SELECT da tabela que estou disparando a trigger, mas isso não deveria ser ignorado por se tratar de uma COMPOUND TRIGGER?, pesquisei bastante e não obtive alguma resposta clara. Exemplo do que estou fazendo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_nome_trigger
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabela
COMPOUND TRIGGER 

AFTER EACH ROW IS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO tabela_log
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS dt_hr,  tb.* 
FROM tabela tb

END AFTER EACH ROW

END
```

Estou utilizando o oracle 11g. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Mas se você só quer inserir um log da própria tabela, porque não usa o :new.coluna...?

Answer (score 2):

O erro `ORA-04091: table is mutating` acontece quando você tentar acessar uma tabela que está sendo modificada dentro de uma `trigger`.
Isso quer dizer que em tempo de execução qualquer tentativa de acesso direto a uma dessas tabelas causará este erro.

A `Compound Trigger` não é uma diretiva que simplesmente vai permitir que você acesse uma dessas tabelas,
na verdade ela de ta ferramentas para que você armazene informações durante toda a execução do processo.
Com isso, você pode ir armazenando informações da sua tabela em "memória" e depois poderá utiliza-lás em suas regras de negócio.

O fato é, só seria realmente necessário criar uma `Compound Trigger`, caso você queira analizar todos os dados da sua tabela durante a execução da sua [DML](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_dml.htm#TDDDG23000).
Qualquer outra situação pode ser resolvida utilizando uma `trigger` normal.

O mais comum para resolver essa sua situação, seria utilizar os dados que você encontra nas [pseudo linhas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18147/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG99934), com o uso do `:OLD` e `:NEW`

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_nome_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabela FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO tabela_log (dt_hr, codigo, descricao)
  VALUES (current_timestamp, :new.codigo, NEW :descricao);

END trg_nome_trigger;
```

Se mesmo assim você quiser acessar sua tabela, e os dados da sua tabela nao precisam necessariamente estar "atualizados", pode-se utilizar a diretiva [PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm) para abrir uma nova transação e executar seus comandos sem que este problema ocorra.

Com essas duas dicas, você já consegue resolver 99% dos problemas com o erro `ORA-04091: table is mutating`.

Mas, se mesmo assim quiser utiliza a `Compound Trigger`, sugiro dar uma olhada nesse [artigo](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html), só que dai será algo bem mais complexo de se resolver.

Comment: Na verdade o mais complicado de tudo é que a tabela que dispara a trigger está relacionada com outras tabelas, que tem ligação direta com a tabela que dispara a trigger, aí ao realizar o inner join ou cruzamentos com outras tabelas, ela dispara o erro de mutating , a questão é muito complexa, apesar de de já ter utilizado outros métodos como simular uma tabela com só com :new e com :old e etc, eu consigo resolver o problema de outra forma, mas não de forma simples e do jeito que eu gostaria que fosse, só queria saber se tem alguma forma simples de resolver o problema. Mas parece que não há.

Comment: Tenta usar o `pragma_autonomous_transaction` então e vê se vai grava os dados corretamente... Só não esqueça do `commit` após o insert.

Comment: Quanto a questão do  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION eu dei uma estudada anteriormente nisso, e pela minha pesquisa existe a possibilidade de o dado a ser analisado não ser 100% confiável, existem situações que ele pode dar problemas, eu fiz testes e realmente deram inconsistências dependendo da forma que se tratava o dado, já tentei buscar em vários fóruns estrangeiros mas não consegui encontrar uma resposta para essa questão, mas é uma caso raro de se utilizar mesmo, vou continuar utilizando outra forma até encontrar uma nova solução.